# Solution to heat equation

Tags: c, differential-equations

When trying to plot the solution of the heat PDE I've found some troubles. The solution that I've found [is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcoBB.png):

Here is the code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define N 10000
 
double f(double x);
double X[N];
double Y[N];
 
int main(){
    int i;
    double b=43351/94400;
    double dx=0.0001;
    X[0]=0;
    Y[0]=b;
    for (i=1; i<N; i++){
    X[i]=X[i-1]+dx;
    Y[i]=f(X[i]);
    }
    FILE* output;
    
    output = fopen("dades.txt", "w");
   
    
    fprintf(output, "x Posició Temperatura\n");
    
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        fprintf(output, "%lf %lf %lf\n", i*dx, X[i], Y[i]);
    }
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}
 
double f(double x){
    
    int n;
    double b=43351/94400;
    for (n=1; n<N; n+=2){
     
        double pi=3.14159265358979323846;
        double t0=0.025;
        double result=b;
        result+=2*(1-pow((-1),n))/(pi*n)*(1-exp(-pow(n,2)*pow(pi,2)*pow(t0,2)))/(pow(n,2)*pow(pi,2))*sin(n*pi*x);
        }
    return result;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to declare a function that calculates the infinite sum for n odd, and then looping it for every x between 0 and 1. The problem is that I don't know how to declare "result" in order to be the sum of all the terms, because if I declare it outside the for loop it doesn't satisfy the boundary conditions.

(Note that I fixed t=0.025).

Comment: `double b=43351/94400;` isn't what you think it is. That's integer division, and results in zero (0). Try `double b=43351./94400;`

Comment: Accordong to the equation, `double result = b` should be moved outside the loop. Otherwise it will only keep the last element n

Comment: Please, never, ever use `pow(-1, i)` to produce an alternating sequence in a real program. Here is even worse, given that in the posted loop `2*(1-pow((-1),n))` is just a replacement for `4.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the equation, you can implement `f` as:

```
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846;

double f(double x)
{
    int n;
    double result=43351.0/94400.0;
    double t0=0.025;

    for (n=1; n<N; n+=2){
        result+=2*(1-pow((-1),n))/(M_PI*n)*(1-exp(-pow(n,2)*pow(M_PI,2)*pow(t0,2)))/(pow(n,2)*pow(M_PI,2))*sin(n*M_PI*x);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Since you are using double, so you have to explicitly add a `.0` otherwise it may be considered as integer.

The declarations of variable are moved outside the loop in order both to clarify the code and ensure the variable `result` gets update instead of being overwritten.

EDIT:

You could improve the function `f` to take the value of `t` as an input. This also aligns with the equation provided. It would then implements this way:

```
double f(double x, double t)
{
    int n;
    double result=43351.0/94400.0;

    for (n=1; n<N; n+=2){
        result+=2*(1-pow((-1),n))/(M_PI*n)*(1-exp(-pow(n,2)*pow(M_PI,2)*pow(t,2)))/(pow(n,2)*pow(M_PI,2))*sin(n*M_PI*x);
    }
    return result;
}
```

EDIT:

The implementation of the math of the equation could be further simplified:

- `a^2 b^2` is same as `(ab)^2`.
- `(-1)^n` with n odd is always `-1`.
- `2*(1-pow((-1),n))` is a replacement for `4`.

Plus, from a performance perspective you can avoid recalculation of repeated terms by putting them in a variable and the use it as you need (for instance the `n^2 pi^2`).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for pointing that out, I corrected the answer

Comment: Please note that, given the posted formula, you can [somehow](https://godbolt.org/z/5cYEfsdq3) separate the calculations of the terms of the series.

Comment: @Bob__ Indeed, I leave these improvements up to the OP